# How to calculate no of pings (rcvd, sent, lost) in a WLAN simulated in OMNET++?

Tags: wifi, simulation, omnet++, inet

I have simulated a WLAN in OMNET using INET framework using its application "PingApp"

Here's my NED code:

```
import inet.applications.pingapp.PingApp;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.node.inet.WirelessHost;
import inet.node.wireless.AccessPoint;
import inet.physicallayer.wireless.ieee80211.packetlevel.Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium;

// TODO documentation
//
network WLAN
{
    parameters:
        int numHosts = default(2);
        **.mgmt.numChannels = 2;
        @display("bgb=645,452");
        
             
             @statistic[numLost](title="pings lost"; record=last,vector; interpolationmode=none);
             @statistic[numOutOfOrderArrivals](title="ping out-of-order arrivals"; record=last,vector; interpolationmode=none);
             


    submodules:

        host[numHosts]: WirelessHost {
            @display("p=287,101");
            wlan[*].mgmt.typename = "Ieee80211MgmtStaSimplified";
        }

        ap: AccessPoint {
            @display("p=111,260");
            wlan[*].mgmt.typename = "Ieee80211MgmtApSimplified";
        }

        radioMedium: Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium {
            @display("p=462,201");
        }
        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
            @display("p=462,320");
        }
}
```

and ini file:

```
[General]
network = WLAN
#cmdenv-output-file = omnetpp.log
#debug-on-errors = true
#record-eventlog = true

**.constraintAreaMinX = 0m
**.constraintAreaMinY = 0m
**.constraintAreaMinZ = 0m
**.constraintAreaMaxX = 500m
**.constraintAreaMaxY = 300m
**.constraintAreaMaxZ = 0m

# access point
**.ap.wlan[*].address = "10:00:00:00:00:00"
**.host[*].**.mgmt.accessPointAddress = "10:00:00:00:00:00"
**.mgmt.frameCapacity = 10 

# ping app (host[0] pinged by others)
**.numApps = 1
**.app[0].typename = "PingApp"
*.host[0].app[0].destAddr = ""
*.host[*].app[0].destAddr = "host[0]"
*.host[*].app[0].sendInterval = 10ms
**.app[*].numLost.statistic-recording = true
**.app[*].numLost.result-recording-modes = "all"


**.wlan[*].mac.retryLimit = 7

**.bandName = "5 GHz (20 MHz)" #,"5 GHz (20 MHz)","5 GHz (40 MHz)","5 GHz (80 MHz)","5 GHz (160 MHz)"
**.opMode = "ac"
#**.opMode = "a"

**.wlan[*].radio.antenna.numAntennas = 8 #maximum number of streams for 802.11ac is 8

**.bitrate = 693.3Mbps

**.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.power = 100mW
**.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.headerBitLength = 100b
**.carrierFrequency = 5GHz
**.wlan[*].radio.receiver.sensitivity = -85dBm
**.wlan[*].radio.receiver.snirThreshold = 4dB

[Config Ping1]
description = "host1 pinging host0"
*.numHosts = 2
```

I have tried all @signal @statistic and
statistic-recording = true, result-recording-modes = "all" etc.

Statistics (Vectors are showing these two sequence vectors: pingRxSeq and pingTxSeq) but I cannot seem to figure out how to get following:

o   How many pings have been sent?
o   How many pings have been received?
o   How is that related to the sendInterval?
o   How many pings have been lost?

Please help!

I have tried to figure it out but nothing is working. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required statistics of pings are recorded. Browse results, go to `Scalars` tab, and write `WLAN.host[1].app[0]` as "module filter" - you should look the following page:

[image]

Where:
`pingTxSeq:count` as well as `Pings sent` is the number of sent pings
`pingRxSeq:count` is the number of successfully received answers to pings

The number of sent pings is directly determined by the value of `sendInterval` and time of the experiment (i.e. next ping is sent every `sendInterval` time). Take a look at your local `src/inet/applications/pingapp/PingApp.ned` or [INET API PingApp](https://doc.omnetpp.org/inet/api-current/neddoc/inet.applications.pingapp.PingApp.html) where parameters of `PingApp` are described.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Definetly helped me where and how result would be shown. 

For some reason this code/simulation was not recording "Scalars" on my PC at all. Only vectors. But now I ran the exact same code (whole folder) on my other PC and it gave me all the results (Scalars as you have shown). Anyway, thanks a lot! cheers!

Comment: When I express run the simulation (faster), it gives me an error:
handleCommand(): no commands supported -- in module (inet::ieee80211::Ieee80211MgmtStaSimplified) WLAN.host[0].wlan[0].mgmt (id=29), at t=0.115314512467s, event #1487

and that's why It doesnot generate .sca file. Can you help me find a solution to this?

thank you :)

Comment: To resolve your error in the NED file add the line `wlan[*].agent.typename = "";` just after the line `wlan[*].mgmt.typename = "Ieee80211MgmtStaSimplified";` (two times).

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much for your time, help and effort. So much appreciation for you. :)